# Trying to create Random quote generator with mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

It work with local DB, but when i created MongoDB Atlas it stoped. Anything wrong with my code?
also it keep creating a db called 'test".

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb+srv://User:Password@cluster0.t4vboa3.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

// Connect to the database
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
.then(() => {
  console.log('Connected to MongoDB successfully!');
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.error('Failed to connect to MongoDB:', err);
});

// Define a schema for the quotes collection
const quoteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  text: {type: String, required: true},
  author: {type: String, required: true}
});

// Create a model for the quotes collection
const Quote = mongoose.model('Quote', quoteSchema);

// This sets up a route that sends the index.html file to the client when they request the root URL.
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

// Serve static files from the "public" directory
app.use(express.static('public'));

// Define an endpoint that returns a random quote from the database
app.get('/api/quotes/random', (req, res) => {
    Quote.countDocuments().exec()
        .then(count => {
            const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
            Quote.findOne().skip(random).exec()
                .then(quote => {
                    res.json({text: quote.text, author: quote.author});
                })
                .catch(err => res.status(500).json({ error: err.message }));
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(500).json({ error: err.message }));
});

// Define the port to listen on
const PORT = 3000;

// Start the Express app listening on the defined port
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhqj4.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7g6S.png)

i tried everything at this point that i know

Comment: What does "stopped working" mean? Please post actual error messages, not just screenshots of the app UI that we don't know anything about

Comment: Is that your real username/password?  If so, you should change them immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue with a database called 'test' being created, it's likely because the `useNewUrlParser` option is set to true. This option automatically creates a database called 'test' if one doesn't already exist. To avoid this, you can set `useNewUrlParser` to false:

```
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: false, useUnifiedTopology: true })
```

Answer (score 0):

When connecting to MongoDB the [connection string](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/#connection-string-uri-format) should include the database name.  If it does not, the database name 'test' will be used.

```
mongodb+srv://user:password@hostname/databasename?options
```

So perhaps something like:

```
const uri = 'mongodb+srv://User:Password@cluster0.t4vboa3.mongodb.net/Quotes?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
```